# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#, api, rest, visual-studio-2017

He buscando durante dias una solucion pero no logro encontrar nada.

Tengo una aplicacion que llama un servicio web (REST) el cual falla cuando se ejecuta desde un Windows server 2012 R2 (Framework 4.5.1 instalado)

El error que me da es `'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.'`

En todos los foros encuentro que dicen de agregar esto antes de la ejecucion de la llamada del API:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Pero el poblema sigue pasando.

Lo raro es que desde un computador con Windows 10, la ejecucion del programa es exitosa.

Desde el servidor 2012 tengo Tls 1.1 y Tls 1.2.

Que otra cosa podria hacer para solucionar este problema?

Gracias

Comment: Ya probaste desactivando o cerrando el antivirus/firewall?

Comment: Probaste las soluciones propuestas en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627977/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send ?

Comment: Si, probe desactivando el antivirus y firewall tambien instale el ultimo .Net Framework, pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: El cliente y el servicio rest están en el mismo servidor o en diferentes? necesitas alguna autenticacion para llamar al servicio?

Comment: El cliente y servidor estan en diferentes partes. Si es necesario una autenticación, la cual usa basic authentication.

Answer (score -1):

tuve que activar tls 1.0 y 1.1 y ahi funciono.

Comment: Cómo lo activaste? Dónde? Podrías [edit] y dar algo más de detalle para otros con el mismo lío ;)